# Receiving the content of one arraylist into another and then empty the first one

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to receive the content of the arraylist `array1` into the arraylist `array2` and then empty the content of the array1:

```
    public ArrayList array1 = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayList array2 = new ArrayList();

    /* array1 contains data and array2 is empty*/

    array2.addAll(array1);
    array1.clear();
    System.out.println(array2);
```

The problem I have is that `array2` is empty `[]`.

When I remove the line `array1.clear();`, it works great and `array2` shows the content `[a1, a2, a3]`.

I thought when `array2` receives the content of `array1` we can clear `array1` without problem. Does it get removed from both place since it's all still in memory?

How can do it the right way?

Comment: Most times you should not be trying to manage memory like this.  Use OOP properly with narrow scopes and let the JVM do your garbage collection for you.

Comment: Calling `array1.clear()` shouldn't affect `array2` in any way here.

Comment: You're sure `array1` isn't empty before calling `allAll`? Could you provide the way you fill `array1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array1.clear()` sets all the objects contained in an arraylist to null. But this does not ensure that all the objects contained in the arraylist will be garbage collected. The objects which have references elsewhere will not be GCed till all references are removed.

And `array1= null` just sets its reference to null and will not be garbage collected till there are references to it and the objects contained in it will also be GCed as explained above.

As you will never know when the GC will be done and hence you cannot force GC by setting your objects to null. The objects will get GCed as and when the objects go out of scope.

Try using `array1= null`..

Or for copying you can also use `clone` method

```
array2= (ArrayList<Object>)array1.clone();
```

Comment: yes, I got another case of arraylist containing arraylists I'll try to make it work with same instructions or worse post a new thread here.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it get removed from both place since it's all still in memory?

```
        // Will do a Shallow Copy. Will not reference a1 in anyway.
        array2 = (ArrayList)array1.clone();

        // The object is still alive and holds a reference.        
        array1.clear();

        // Once array1 = null, it will be eligible for Garbage Collection.
        array1 = null;
```

Hope this helps.